# Does upgrading apache via apt-get install wipe source/config files?

Tags: apt, server, apache2

It seems like the most common way to upgrade apache on ubuntu is by running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
```

Does upgrading apache via apt-get install wipe source and/or config files? The name `install` leads me to believe this would be a fresh (re)install as opposed to a simple update.

Additionally, will I need to restart the server after updating?

Answer (score 1):

Never. Configuration files are only created when those do not exist. Otherwise those are left as is. Would break usage if those are deleted or changed back to default. If someone needs to update a configuration file editing is done by creating commands to alter the configursation. `sed` is a popular tool for this. Example:

```
echo "hello" | sed 's/hello/bye/g' 
bye
```

Only the "purge" option will delete configuration files.

Even if there are incompatibility issues in configurations you will get warnings for a long period (as in "{option} is deprecated; please use {new option}. Apache and MySQL had a couple of those in the past 10, 15 years.

> Additionally, will I need to restart the server after updating?

No. Only kernel updates need a reboot and even those you can postpone.

You will want to restart the apache service if that is not done by itself. If only just to check if all still works as intended.

> wipe source files

What source files? The files related to apache will be overwritten by their new versions when there are new versions. If you mean the installed files when installing apache from source: that version will not be overwritten by apache. Installing from source is something you do in /opt/  so not at the locations `apt` installs.

Comment: The "source files" i meant here are the web app files apache is serving (for example the files in /var/www/html/ )

Comment: Config files may not get deleted with "install" but would "install" overwrite them?

Comment: =no never= user files are never overwritten or deleted. Those are only created when it does not exist.

Comment: More correctly, config files (which are in `/etc`) are _compared_ to the files on the system. If the existing config file is identical to the one delivered in the previous package, it will be replaced. If there are any differences, you will be prompted whether to keep the original, replace it, or run `diff` to see what's changed. Your "source" files will **never** be touched.